# Making http get in angularjs foreach loop with post results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, angular-promise

I have a web app the logs the ip addresses,connection and disconnection time, and number of bits transferred of a visitor in a media stream. Before I display this information in a table, I run through the results of the search and add things like connection length and bits per second in an `$angular.forEach()` loop. I'd like to make an `$http get` request to a db to get the location and isp information of the ip address. I tried adding the get request directly to the `forEach` loop but I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'method' of "theIp"`. I tested the cgi file I used to connect to the db with one address so it does work. The query always returns an ip.

```
$http.post(...)
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $scope.results = result.data.data;

                    angular.forEach($scope.results, function(conn) {
                        conn.connected = moment.utc(conn.connected).toDate();
                        conn.disconnected = moment.utc(conn.disconnected).toDate();
                        conn.connected = moment(conn.connected).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                        conn.disconnected = moment(conn.disconnected).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

                        conn.secondsElapsed = moment(conn.disconnected).diff(moment(conn.connected), 'seconds');
                        conn.bitsPerSecond = conn.traffic / conn.secondsElapsed;
                        //console.log("connection is " + conn.streamName);

                        $http.get("thedb.cgi?action=get&addr=", conn.ip) //addr is name of ip argument
                        .success(function(ipLocation){
                            console.log(ipLocation); //just want to fetch info correctly before adding it to view
                        });
                    });
```

I keep reading about promises but I thought that if I am running through the array of results anyway, why would there be a need to make another promise?

Edit: Ok so I tried some of the fixes suggested and now I have a different issue. I got a response from the api (I forgot a backslash) but empty json objects are being passed in. Now my `$http` request looks like:

```
$http.get("/api/thedb.cgi", {action:'get', addr:conn.ip})
.then(function(ipLocation){
    console.log(ipLocation);
});
```

But it's sending blank JSON objects and doing requests long after the table is drawn. As requested here's the view for the relevant part of the table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in results>
        <td style="text-align: left;">{{result.ip}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{result.connected}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;" ng-hide="liveListenerCheck">{{result.disconnected}}</td>
        <td ng-module="" style="text-align: right;" ng-hide="result.secondsElapsed < 60">{{Math.floor(result.secondsElapsed/60) | number:0}}:{{result.secondsElapsed % 60 | leadingZero}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;" ng-show="result.secondsElapsed < 60">>1</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">{{result.bitsPerSecond | number:0}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would add another column for the location of the ip addresses

Comment: This should work (except that it'd be better, if you have control over the backend API, to expose a single API to request multiple results in one shot).

Comment: You only need to create a promise if you do something on another thread (what angular $http does)... So to don't interfere the main thread (and with that your ui/your whole app) you do an AJAX call which performs its data on a Background Thread... And because you don't know when and if the Background Thread returns its value, you build up a promise which is a function called when the BGT returns... :-) thats just to clear the promise

Comment: To your problem... when you perform the line $scope.results = result.data.data; if you maybe ng-repeat the property $scope.results, you first put the whole return of your get to the view... thats what you don't want.... (if I understand you right)

Comment: could you post your html code regarding this too?

Comment: This feels like a [$sasqwatch](http://www.guidokoch.ch/jobplattform/jobsuche.html) to me.  You essentially want to fetch some data from the server, then make some more calls to the server and modify the data that you just fetched before displaying it.  This is **definitely** something that the server should handle in one call.

Comment: Added the html. I believe I am putting the `$scope.results` in an `ng-repeat` but now the issue is it's doing the geo-location call well after it draws the table and sending blank JSONs. I'm guessing it loses scope of the results but idk.

Comment: @Claies $sasqwatch? Sorry I'm new to the dev world and not quite sure what that means. So instead of modifying the JSONs, is there a way to have a separate array to display along side the results instead?

Comment: Sorry, if you watch the video that term would make more sense, but basically it is unnecessary calls or $watchers that adversely affect performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out code looks like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.results, function(conn, key){
                $http.get("thedb.cgi?action=get&addr="+conn.ip, { cache: true})
                .then(function(ipLocation) {
                    console.log(ipLocation);
                    var locationResults = ipLocation.data; 
                    conn.country = locationResults.country;
                    //... more assignments
                });
            });
```

Now I need to figure out how to limit the number of asynchronous requests for large queries so the page doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
$http.get("thedb.cgi?action=get&addr=", conn.ip)
```

should say this

```
$http.get("thedb.cgi?action=get&addr=" + conn.ip)
```

also, I'm not sure that will work... [as per docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods) you should be doing this

```
$http.get("thedb.cgi", {action:'get', addr:conn.ip}).then(....)
```

Additionaly, if you want to modify the `$scope.results` like this

```
...
angular.forEach($scope.results, function(conn) {
    conn.connected = moment.utc(conn.connected).toDate();
...
```

it souldn't work... you should do something like this

```
...
angular.forEach($scope.results, function(conn, key, obj) {
    obj[key].connected = moment.utc(conn.connected).toDate();
...
```

Comment: Thanks your first suggestion seems to call the api now but now its sending blank JSONs. So far it seems like editing the results like I have seems to work, I see a different JSON object in the Chrome console with the additional info I added.